# let $A$ be a $4 \times 4$ invertible real matrix then which of the following is not true.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$  be a $4 \times 4$ invertible real matrix  then which of the following is not true
>
> 1) the rows of $a$ form a basis of $\Bbb R^4$.
>
> 2) null space of $A$ contains only the $0$ vector
>
> 3)$A$ has 4 distinct eigenvalues
>
> 4) image of the linear transformation $x$ to $\mathbb R^4$ is $\mathbb R^4$

Since $A$ is invertible option 2 is always true. i am not sure about another options please help me .

Comment: options 1 ,2 and 4 are ture

Comment: i also thought that can you explain a little bit sir please

Comment: i did. Please like it.

Comment: sir how to like please tell me?

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

Options (1), (2), (4) are indeed true.

With respect to option (3): is it *necessarily* the case that $A$ has 4 ***distinct*** eigenvalues? (Think of the identity matrix...)

Comment: it is "necessary"

Comment: option3 is not true

Comment: What I'm getting at @Praphulla is that *some* invertible 4 by 4 matrices *might* have 4 distinct eigenvalues, but not all such matrices do. Hence such a matrix *need not* have four distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: @Tattwamasi Indeed it is not true for all such matrices. It might be true for *some* four by four invertible matrices, but it is not true of *all* 4 by 4 invertible matrices. (Oops, I just saw my typo that you were referring to!!)

Comment: @amWhy .. yeah right.

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks for the support. Ug - my laptop is dying - the display is really funky, so need a new one! Hope you are having a great POET'S Day! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the $4\times 4$ identity matrix. It has only one non zero eigenvalue, which is $1$.

Answer (score 3):

AS $A$ is invertible, its $4$ rows are invertible. Hence it forms a basis for $R^4$.
As the rank$A$ is $4$,by rank-nullity theorem nullspace is $0$. Hence onto. Hence the image is $R^4$. For option 3 consider $I_4$.

Comment: thank sir in my mind exactly same was going but i could not express it .